# Windows password policy

Tags: change-password

When i try to set a password for windows as

```
net user usera "a""b&cd"
```

I could set the password correctly ie(a"b&cd)and could login with user id and password
but when i try to set the password as

```
net user usera "a""b&c""d"
```

I am not able to login

Is there any issue when there are two ""(double quotes) in the password because i am trying this at different locations in string and only one " is allowed in password.
Let me know if i am missing anything. is there some other way?
By the way i have windows xp home edition. will this work for other editions ?

Thanks in advance
AK.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this:

```
net user administrator abc
```

where `administrator` = user name and `abc` = password